# More pythonic way for exceptions?

Tags: python, django, exception

I have a method that must return one of three objects depending on their existence.

My implementation

```
try:
    return Model.objects.get(param=param)
except Model.DoesNotExist as ex:
    # go to the next verification
    pass

try:
    return RelatedModel.objects.get(param=param).model
except RelatedMolel.DoesNotExist as ex:
    # get the default model
    pass

return Model.objects.get_default()
```

So question for the guru of python - is it a more pythonic implementation than inner try/catch blocks or ?

```
try:
    return Model.objects.get(param=param)
except Model.DoesNotExist as ex:

    try:
        return RelatedModel.objects.get(param=param).model
    except RelatedModel.DoesNotExist as ex:

        return Model.objects.get_default()
```

Comment: "pythonic" = "take the obvious path to the goal", mostly.

Comment: @millimoose the both paths are obvious enough for me =) but what is more obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (`import this`):

> Flat is better than nested.

I would prefer the first version in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The docs tell us:

> `ObjectDoesNotExist` is defined in `django.core.exceptions`. `DoesNotExist` is a subclass of the base `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception that is provided on every model class as a way of identifying the specific type of object that could not be found.

So what I'd do is:

```
queries = [lambda: Model.objects.get(param=param),
             lambda: RelatedModel.objects.get(param=param).model,
             lambda: Model.objects.get_default()]

for query in queries:
    try:
        return query()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Arguably this way isn't "obvious", but it's both flat, reduces redundancy, and keeps related things together.

Comment: "queries" or "attempts" ?

Comment: @TravisGriggs "queries" is excellent actually.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really consider myself as "python Guru", anyway here's my advice:

- in order to make your code easy to maintain, I've learned that it's a good idea to limit the output points of your code.
- another good practice for readability is to use the blocks as expected: when there is an `if` block, avoid temptation to put the `return` inside it: just use an `else` block, and I find this applicable also for `try...except` blocks. Of course, this is valid only if deepness is not too important.

Therefore, I would write this:

```
try:
    res = Model.objects.get(param=param)
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    try:
        res = RelatedModel.objects.get(param.param).model
    except RelatedModel.DoesNotExist:
        res = Model.objects.get_default()
return res
```

As you make no usage of `ex`, there is no need to specify its assignment.

Comment: I very much disagree that fiddling with the local variable makes this easier to read. To find out what this function returns you have to work backwards to see what gets assigned to `res`. It's a point of opinion whether making the function have less local state versus having a single return is better.

Comment: On purpose, I wrote "to maintain": I agree it's not easier to read, but at least you have to follow all assignments of your return value, to see how it evolves. Obviously, all these assignments have to be close to the end of the function code. The fact that multiple `return`s may exist does not simplify this work, and may need exactly the same research work.

Comment: In which I'd try to reduce the amount of research work, instead of just shuffling deck chairs around to improve an unrelated property of the code. (Which I've tried in my answer.)